# Dividing hh:mm:ss by an integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to split time (hh:mm:ss) by an integer. For example `13:14:24` / `12`.

If I convert it into date and divide:

```
new Date( date.getMonth()+1 + " " +  
          date.getDate() + ", " + 
          date.getFullYear() + " " + 
          "13:14:24") / 12;
```

I get a really long number `119579922000`, is it date / 12 in milliseconds? I need the result to be in the same hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: I think you are better of by dividing doing (hh*3600 + mm * 60 + ss) / 12 and converting that back to the hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: @martijnn2008 Nothing in this question signals Java instead of JavaScript.

Comment: @Anonymous A question with exactly similar title exists, but for SQL, so SO won't let me post.

Comment: Is the time like a time of day (or does the date have meaning too?).  If you divide the date number by 12, the result will be a twelfth of the elapsed time between midnight Jan 1, 1970 and your date.  I assume you want a twelfth of the time elapsed from some *other* reference point though

Comment: @ne1410s not the date number, just `13:14:24`. So 12 equal parts of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var h = 13, m = 14, s = 24;

var secsSinceMidnight = (h*3600) + (m*60) + s;
var oneTwelth = secsSinceMidnight / 12;

h = Math.floor(oneTwelth / 3600);
m = Math.floor( (oneTwelth % 3600) / 60);
s = Math.floor( (oneTwelth % 3600) % 60);

console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
```

Here is an alternative approach using the [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) library, which is my personal choice extension for date handling in JavaScript:

```
var midnight = Date.create().beginningOfDay();
var secsSinceMidnight = Date.create().secondsSince(midnight);
console.log( (secsSinceMidnight/12).secondsAfter(midnight) );
```

To explain the last line: `secondsAfter` is a function defined on the `Number` type. It is returning a `Date` object, which is then sent to `console.log()`.

Comment: Nice to know about sugar, but I'm considering using moment.js now since pure javascript is a pain for date manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Just another plain-old-javascript alternative, but done in one line of code.

```
   return (new Date((date - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) % 86400000 / divisor )).toUTCString().split(' ')[4];
```

It adjusts by timezone (minutes) as the math is in UTC. Next divides the modulo (86400000 milliseconds = 1 day) by a divisor. Returns a formatted time string.

**Working Example:**

```js
function getTimeSlice( date, divisor ) {
  return (new Date((date - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) % 86400000 / divisor )).toUTCString().split(' ')[4];
}

// Test
var test = new Date( );
test.setHours(13, 14, 24, 0);
stdout.innerHTML = getTimeSlice( test, 12);
```

```html
<div id="stdout"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but it might help to have a couple of simple functions, one to convert h:m:s to seconds, and one to convert seconds to h:m:s.

E.g.

```
// Convert H:M:S to seconds
// Seconds are optional (i.e. n:n is treated as h:s)
function hmsToSeconds(s) {
  var b = s.split(':');
  return b[0]*3600 + b[1]*60 + (+b[2] || 0);
}

// Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss
function secondsToHMS(secs) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}
  var sign = secs < 0? '-':'';
  secs = Math.abs(secs);
  return sign + z(secs/3600 |0) + ':' + z((secs%3600) / 60 |0) + ':' + z(secs%60 |0);
}
```

So if you want to divide a time by 12, then:

```
console.log(secondsToHMS(hmsToSeconds('13:14:24')/12)); // 01:06:12
```